# How to change a Heroku domain to a custom domain?

Tags: heroku, dns

To cut to the chase, I have an arbitrary Heroku domain that I'd like to transfer to a custom domain. I've never done this before. I've looked into it but haven't found a clear enough answer broken up into steps.

Comment: I haven't used heroku before... Is it kind of like web hosting for web applications?

Comment: If so, you could just buy a domain and point the A DNS record towards the Heroku server IP.  It shouldn't be that difficult.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1) Buy a domain from a domain-registrar ([godaddy.com](http://www.godaddy.com), [networksolutions.com](http://www.networksolutions.com))

2) Add the domain to your heroku app => heroku domains:add

3) You'll see an option to alter DNS records on your domain service provider's account dashboard, add a "www" C-Name DNS record and point it to your heroku app (e.g. yourapp.herokuapp.com)

Comment: everyone was missing this 'buy domain' step :-)

Comment: official doc: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: This technically works but the custom domain just forwards to the heroku arbitrary domain. It would be much better to have the custom domain work without forwarding.

Comment: @XoXo the official docs are terrible for this topic and Heroku now directs free users to.. stack overflow for support. These instructions are much better: https://www.codejava.net/heroku/add-custom-domain-names-for-apps

Answer (score 6):

This article explains the process in detail:

http://lifesforlearning.com/heroku-with-godaddy/

Example using www.example.com for example.herokuapp.com

1. In your heroku app use commands: 
   heroku domains:add www.example.com
   heroku domains:add example.com
2. Go to your Godaddy specific domain page.
3. Clear all records you don't need. Add a CNAME record using www as host. For your target, go use command 'heroku domains' within your app and copy the url given for the www.example.com domain. Add an A record using @ as host and 50.63.202.1 as target (from documentation).
4. You are done, however it will take time for this change to propagate. In the interim use forwarding. Scroll down to the bottom of the GoDaddy site and enter forwarding information using https:// or http://, example.herokuapp.com, permanent (301), and forward only. Don't click the checkbox to update DNS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the domain to your heroku app => heroku domains:add domainname
2. Go to your domain service provider account and update/add a "www" CName DNS record and point it to your heroku app (e.g. appname.herokuapp.com)

Note: If you are ever going to add ssl on your websote, then you need to move your dns records to heroku with pointDNS(addon available on heroku - free for 1 domain and 20 dns records).

Answer (score 0):

Please read their documentation to know more details about how to do that: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **summary** of the processes from **heroku documentation**

[Summary of steps - Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#summary-of-steps)